# tag a not working on pure javascript on onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I've run into the following problem. I made a landing page, made links to page sections through pure javascript, everything seems to be working, super. But, I wanted to add a regular <а></а> link and it turns out it doesn't work, I understand that the reason lies in event.preventDefault(); but if this is removed, then the main script breaks

```
document.querySelector('.nav').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let elementOffset = 0;

    let parent = document.querySelector('.nav');
    let menuItem = parent.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');

    if(event.target.classList.contains('nav__link')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
            menuItem[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }

    let elementId = event.target.getAttribute('data-scroll');
    let element = event.target;

    if(elementId && element){
        elementOffset = getElementScrollOffset(elementId);

        scrollToTop(elementOffset);

        element.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

```
<div class="header__inner">
                <div class="header__logo" data-scroll="#intro"></div>
                <nav class="nav" id="nav">
                    <a class="nav__link active" href="#" data-scroll="#about">about</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#services">services</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#mods">Сmods</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#updates">updates</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#footer">Кfooter</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Discord</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

If you remove event.preventDefault(); instead of going to it, it takes me to the top page. Yes, I understand that you can insert a link outside the .nav element, but I need it there. Help pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do in you click handler is to prevent the execution of the code if the clicked link is not an in-page anchor. You could do this by checking that the `href` of the clicked `<a>` element is not equal to `#`. You   could do this by modifying your handler as follows:

```js
document.querySelector('.nav').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('href') !== '#') { return; }

  /* rest of handler logic remains the same */
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4rcg7jxm/) for reference.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! I have the last question, now everything works with the PC version, but if you try to follow this link from your phone, then for some reason it does not work, I tried it from chrome and safari. If you know, please write, it will be generally super)

Comment: @spider5414 In what way does it not work?

Comment: The last link does not work on mobile devices, it works for me personally. A friend of mine has iOS 15, came from safari and the link <a class="nav__link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Discord</a> doesn't work
, the second friend who logged in with Google also does not work with chrome, but after he cleared the cache, it worked. That is, they just click, and nothing happens, I thought it was in the cache, and each time updating the css style file, they change the version, for example like this - style.css?v0.3

Comment: but it didn't work for everyone.

Comment: I would ask those friends to try to use their browser debugging tools to look for any errors logged to the console.

Comment: solved the problem, it was necessary with each update of the css or javascript file, change its version. For example - <link src="style.css?v1.2" or <script src="script.js?v1.2"